# Tar uncompresses folder, how to change its name?

Tags: command-line, directory, tar, wget

I'm crerating a script that downloads mongo c driver:

```
wget -O mongo.tar.gz https://... \
    && tar -xzvf mongo.tar.gz \
    && cd mongo \
    && ...
```

However it fails in the `cd mongo` part because the actual folder name when I uncompress the tar is `mongo-c-driver-1.7.0`. I cannot rely on this name. How to modify it without knowing how the name is going to look lile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply a sed command to *transform* the name. From [`man tar`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/tar.1)

```
 --transform, --xform EXPRESSION
       use sed replace EXPRESSION to transform file names
```

So:

```
wget -O - https://... |
    tar -xzv --transform 's:^[^/]*:mongo:'
```

`s:^[^/]*:mongo:` replaces everything upto the first `/` with `mongo`.  You can pipe the file directly to `tar` (hence I used `-O -` in wget, and dropped the `-f` option in tar).

Alternatively, you can prune the first component and extract in a directory of your choice:

```
mkdir -p mongo && wget -O - https://... |
    tar -xzv --strip-components=1 -C mongo
```

Where:

```
 --strip-components=NUMBER
       strip NUMBER leading components from file names on extraction
 -C, --directory DIR
       change to directory DIR
```